# TcpListener doesn't detect connection

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have been doing a client-server application in these days. I made a server part based on examples to launch a TcpListener and It seems to be working well.
However, It's not able to detect client connections, while the client says that It connected to the given ip and port.

Here is my code for the server side:

```
    internal static void RunServer()
    {
        // Create a TCP/IP (IPv4) socket and listen for incoming connections.
        ServerLogger.LogStatus("Starting listener...");
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Server.PORT + 2);
        listener.Start();
        ServerLogger.LogStatus("Starting thread listener...");
        tlisten = new Thread(Listen);
        tlisten.Start();
        ServerLogger.LogStatus("Starting receiver...");
        treceiver = new Thread(Receiver);
        treceiver.Start();
        ServerLogger.LogStatus("All done!");
    }

    internal static void Listen()  // Listen to incoming connections.
    { 
       while (running)
        {
            ServerLogger.LogStatus("Waiting for a connecion....");
            TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            // The below code never runs on client connection.
            ServerLogger.LogStatus("Accepting and Creating cert!");
            // Create a new certification
            byte[] serverCertificatebyte = Certificate.CreateSelfSignCertificatePfx("Test" + IP + RandomString(5),
                new DateTime(2015, 12, 26),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month + 1, DateTime.Today.Day), RandomString(20));
            ServerLogger.LogStatus("Created certificate!");
            X509Certificate serverCertificate = new X509Certificate(serverCertificatebyte);
            tcpclientbytecerts[tcpClient] = serverCertificatebyte;
            tcpclientcerts[tcpClient] = serverCertificate;
            ServerLogger.LogInfo("Sending Certificate!");
            // Send SSL certification in bytes
            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(serverCertificatebyte, 0, serverCertificatebyte.Length);
            ServerLogger.LogInfo("Certificate sent to the client!");
            Logger.Log(serverCertificatebyte.ToString());
            // process it
            ServerLogger.LogInfo("Processing");
            ProcessClient(tcpClient, serverCertificate);
            ServerLogger.LogInfo("Processed!");
        }
    }
```

Client side:

```
    private SSL(string ip, int port)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test");
        if (!PrivacyHelper.IsInvocationAllowed())
        {
            Terminate();
        }
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test2 " + ip + " - " + port);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test3 " + IsLocalIpAddress(ip));
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        //client.Connect(ip, port);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test4 " + client.Connected); // <- This is true
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test5");
        Byte[] cert = new Byte[65535];
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test6");
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(cert, 0, cert.Length);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test7");
        byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test8");
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) { Array.Reverse(intBytes);}
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test9");
        byte[] result = intBytes;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Cert: " + result);
        certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(result);
        //client.GetStream().Read()
    }
```

The client seems to be able to connect, It even returns true and says that It's connected. The server side doesn't detect It though. Any ideas?

Comment: What is Server.PORT+2 ? Why +2?

Comment: Server.Port is the gameserver's port. Let's say 28015 is the port, 28016 is the query port. Thats why I do +2

Comment: Before you ask at new SSL(), I already ddi the +2. So It connects to the 28017 port.